# Getting error during J2EE configuration

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, configuration

I was trying to launch JRun using /opt/jrun4/bin/jrun but it showing some inconsistent behavior which is why its not running properly, any solution?

Comment: what do you mean by inconsistent or not running properly? it is difficult to help without having stacktrace or the information you provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution..
Launch JRun by using the following command:

**/yourJAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar /opt/jrun4/lib/jrun.jar -start cfusion**

it worked. thanks everyone